# Handling an event just once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have this piece of code:

```
var tracked = false;
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // do stuff on each click
    if(!tracked) {
        // track interaction just once
        tracked = true;
    }
});
```

.. but I want to make it more elegant cause I can't have `tracked` var everywhere for each interactive. So I'm thinking of this:

```
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // do stuff on each click
    $('.button').one('click', function(e){
        // track interaction just once
    });
});
```

... but it doesn't look so nice. Can it be better?

Edited to add: The button toggles an element which I need it to do on each click, but track the interaction only once, not on each click.

Comment: to be honest, it's unclear what you require - can you explain the use case - your second bit of code would not behave the same as the first

Comment: @JaromandaX The button toggles a div which I need it to do on each click, but track the interaction only once, not on each click.

Comment: In that case your second code block is definitely not right, as the `.one` would apply only on the second click, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is all you need. You can use this in concert with `.on()` to add multiple event listeners to the same button so you can fire different events and disable some but not others.

the `.one()` event will fire once then remove itself, the additional `.on()` click event will remain and continue to fire.

```js
// add a listener that will only fire once
$('.button').one('click', function(e){
    console.log('one click event');
});

// add another listener that will continue to fire
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
    console.log('regular click event');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Click Me</button>
```

If you want it as compact as possible you can use some jquery chaining.

```
$('.button').one('click', function(e){
    // tracking code
}).on('click', function(e){
    // toggling code
});
```

Comment: The button toggles a div which I need it to do on each click, but track the interaction only once, not on each click.

Comment: @3zzy I've updated my answer to address this with multiple event listeners. You should clarify this in your question.

Comment: @3zzy I've also updated to include a more compact version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

*Another* option would be something like

```js
function oneTime(el) {
  console.log("ok");
  el.onclick = null;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="oneTime(this);">test</button>
```

But I believe [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is the **best option**.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as your code with the `.one()` function, though with one less callback. I feel like it is more elegant.

```js
$('#selector').bind('click', function() {
       $(this).unbind('click');
       console.log('Clicked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='selector'>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button').data( "tracked", false ).on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).data( "tracked" ) !== true ) {
        $(this).data( "tracked", true );
        // do stuff on each click
    }
});
```